# Ненужное увеличение на мобильных

Tags: html, css

Заданы такие настройки viewport:

```
viewport: 'width=480, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1',
```

Это необходимо для того чтобы дизайн на маленьких разрешениях выглядел также как на 480. Но по умолчанию при посещении сайта весь контент увеличивается и приходится уменьшать масштаб, чтобы всё было видно. Как убрать это увеличение по умолчанию?

Проблема здесь, в моб.версии:

http://wd38.ru/projects/site-new-smile/

Comment: А как вы поняли, что у вас проблема? По ссылке, что вы скинули всё работает. Ну... Разве что, если зайти с ПК, включить отладчик браузера, а потом переключить в режим мобильного устройства, то viewport так и остаётся `<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">`. Но если потом обновить страницу, то всё становится хорошо: `<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=480; initial-scale=0.7; maximum-scale=1">`.

Answer (score 1):

Заменить строку: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=480, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

На строку: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">`

Comment: такой способ не помог

Comment: А если так: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

Comment: Читайте вопрос внимательнее: Необходимо чтобы дизайн на маленьких разрешениях выглядел также как на 480

Comment: Тогда только через медиа-запрос: @media screen (max-width: 480px). Возможно как-то можно ещё через JS...

Comment: через медиа запрос нужно менять дизайн. Нужно чтобы просто было масштабирование